# Puppet Cron setting $vairable as minute aswell as */

Tags: variables, cron, puppet

This is hard to explain for me, however.

I want to push a time off set to puppet for a cron job.

```
define cron::job (
  $url,
  $time_offset,
  $ensure = 'present',
  $minute = 5 + $time_offset,

)
```

Then in my actual job I want to use */ as well as the minute variable. Is this possible? As my current implementation is failing and I can't seem to find the answer in the docs which suggests I'm going about this the complete incorrect way.

This is my cron job.

```
  cron { "job":
    command => "wget -O - --save-cookies cookies.txt --load-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies  https://${url}/ >/dev/null 2>/dev/null",
    user    => 'housekeeper',
    minute  => '*/$minute',
    ensure  => $ensure,
  }
```

I would appreciate any feedback / suggestions.

Would I be better off just using a set minute rather than every 5 minutes for example?

The reason I want to do this, is I want to leave the cron jobs the same and just pass an offset to the class for each site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
define cron::job (
  $url,
  $time_offset,
) {
  $minute = 5 + $time_offset
  cron { "cron ${name}":
    ensure  => present,
    command => "wget -O - --save-cookies cookies.txt --load-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies  https://${url}/ >/dev/null 2>/dev/null",
    user    => 'housekeeper',
    minute  => "*/${minute}",
    require => User['housekeeper'],
  }
}

user { 'housekeeper':
  ensure => present,
}

cron::job { 'job1':
  url => 'http://example1.com',
  time_offset => 10,
}
cron::job { 'job2':
  url => 'http://example2.com',
  time_offset => 15,
}
```

Then

```
[root@centos-72-x64 ~]# puppet apply /tmp/foo.pp 
Notice: Compiled catalog for centos-72-x64 in environment production in 0.21 seconds
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/User[housekeeper]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Cron::Job[job2]/Cron[cron job2]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Cron::Job[job1]/Cron[cron job1]/ensure: created
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.05 seconds
```

And

```
[root@centos-72-x64 ~]# cat /var/spool/cron/housekeeper
# HEADER: This file was autogenerated at 2016-04-12 11:29:15 +0000 by puppet.
# HEADER: While it can still be managed manually, it is definitely not recommended.
# HEADER: Note particularly that the comments starting with 'Puppet Name' should
# HEADER: not be deleted, as doing so could cause duplicate cron jobs.
# Puppet Name: cron job2
*/20 * * * * wget -O - --save-cookies cookies.txt --load-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies  https://http://example2.com/ >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
# Puppet Name: cron job1
*/15 * * * * wget -O - --save-cookies cookies.txt --load-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies  https://http://example1.com/ >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Perfect, it was just a cause of using double quotes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to hear that.